# Interpreting a sudden leap in residuals

Tags: regression, time-series, residuals

What would this situation below mean?

[image: here]

Is this heteroskedasticity (or something else)?

Horizontal axis is time, vertical axis is quantity (of production sold).

Comment: What are these data? What are the axes here? Is this time series? This isn't answerable at present.

Comment: @gung, edited the question.

Comment: How can you sell fewer than 0 products?

Comment: @gung, These are residuals - the difference between model and real sales. So it looks like there was a huge underestimation of the model in 154 periods and then a huge overestimation, somewhy..

Comment: Right.  (It does say "residuals" in the title ;-). How was the model fit? It looks like people held off on purchasing for a bit, & then everyone made the purchases they had been needing to make for a while. Do the data cover the lead up to a huge sale? Does this span the economic collapse in 2008? Etc.

Comment: @gung, Unfortunatelly, all I have is this graph, so I need to make my conclusions/guesses based only on this given information. I have neither the real data, nor the model.. And there are no years - just time periods 1+, so it's just a study example, not a real one, I think.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). I don't really know what to tell you without more information. Presumably there was something covered / discussed earlier in the course / book that provides a hint regarding what the teacher has in mind here.

Comment: I suggest you scrape this graph picking off the values that were used to make the graph ... post the values you get from the scraping and perhaps some good analysis will detect some level shifts and maybe  even some time trend variables. Residuals are just an adjusted Y thus one can treat them in a standard time series fashion.